# Не могу сделать удаление с помощью checkbox`ов и RedBean

Tags: php, html

Мой код на данный момент выглядит так, мне кажется я близок к решению своей проблемы, но столкнулся с проблемой, как получить имена именно выбранных чекбоксов и если их несколько, наверное нужно делать это через массив

так же если вы найдете какие то другие ошибки, не откажусь от критики и помощи в исправлении

```
<form action="" method="post">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Метка на удаление<input type="submit" value="Удалить" name="del"></th>
                                    <th>Название</th>
                                    <th>Логотип</th>
                                    <th>Победы</th>
                                    <th>Поражения</th>
                                    <th>WinRate</th>
                                </tr>
                            </form>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <?php

                        require "db.php";

                        $teams = R::findAll('teams');
                        $data = $_POST;
                        if(isset($data['del']) && sizeof($data['del'])){
                                $del = R::load('teams', $data['del']  );
                                R::trash($del);
                            }

                        foreach ($teams as $team) {

                            echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label class="btn btn-primary">
                                            <input type="checkbox"  autocomplete="off" name="del[' . $team['id'] . ']">
                                        </label>
                                    </td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $team['team'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td><img src="' . $team['image'] . '" style="width: 30px"></td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $team['wins'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $team['lose'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $team['winrate'] . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Заменил, как сказали ниже и появилась такая ошибка: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Проблема была в том, что форма заканчивалась раньше, чем происходило заполнение таблицы через php, я просто перенес начало формы до открытия таблицы и закрытие формы после таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно

```
if(isset($data['del']) && sizeof($data['del'])){
    $del = R::load('teams', $data['del']  );
    R::trash($del);
}
```

переделать на

```
if(isset($data['del']) && sizeof($data['del'])){
    foreach($data['del'] as $del_id) {
        $del = R::load('teams', $del_id);
        R::trash($del);
    }
}
```

и

```
<input type="checkbox"  autocomplete="off" name="del[' . $team['id'] . ']">
```

заменить на

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="' . $team['id'] . '">
```

а также форме добавить enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Спасибо, заменил, как вы сказали и появилась такая ошибка:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()